# Export Highcharts bubble lat/lon map trough their server

Tags: javascript, php, graph, highcharts, latitude-longitude

TL;DR

Does somebody know how to export the bubble map with lat, lon points, and why is my code rendering empty map?

---

I am trying to export Highcharts bubble chart trough their server `export.highcharts.com`, but all I get is empty map with no cities on it.

When you go to http://export.highcharts.com/ set `Constructor` to `Map`, paste this code to `Options` textarea http://pastebin.com/ZGWme6rJ (too long to paste here) in and click `Preview`, you'll see that it generates blank map, with nothing on it (remove text from `Callback` textarea on the site), but if you'd use it in a graph, you get this result: http://jsfiddle.net/2ubcsgbe/

I managed to export regions map without any problems using this code: http://pastebin.com/XqhdN48B (you can test it at http://export.highcharts.com)

I also googled and read their API & docs, but could not find any examples of how you should export such map. Does somebody have idea or example of how to export such map trough their export server?

Ps.: I can not use their exporting module, as I am manipulating the image on my server with PHP & mPDF. And I also can not use any other libraries.

Thanks.

Comment: The code here http://pastebin.com/EgKWwXkD does not match your code here http://jsfiddle.net/jLjdao17/. The pastebin code throws error. Also, I am confused about why you say you cannot use their exporting module but you are, in fact, using their exporting module: http://export.highcharts.com/.

Comment: @wergeld Thanks for info, I edited the code and now they are indeed matching, but the export site still prints only empty map. And what I meant by their "exporting module" was their PhantomJS thingie.

Comment: Why dont you just include export.js module? Or is this considered "any other library"? It would do this for you: http://jsfiddle.net/2ubcsgbe/1/

Comment: @wergeld Very simple and I did mention it in my question: I am working with that file on my server with PHP and mPDF. Users are not allowed to download just chart image, only PDF that has more data than just graph inside. Ps.: i have it included, as thats only way to use `chart.getSVGForExport()` which I am using now and that solved all my problems.

Comment: Ah, okay. You are wrapping your chart exported content in more content.

Comment: @wergeld yep exactly. Otherwise I would just add button mapped to export option. But that's not really an option for me here. But if I knew they had export svg functionality, I would save myself like 4 hours or more? :D

Answer (score 1):

I found out that Highcharts has functions `chart.getSVG()` and `chart.getSVGForExport()`

So instead of me manually getting data from the charts and making my own functions for hours, now I am just using `chart.getSVGForExport()` and sending data it returns by to their export server and it works like a charm...

Don't forget that you need their `export.js` to have access to this functionality.

Man, I just wasted so much time doing this manually...